# Add several map elements with d3.js to a google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, d3.js

I'm working on a map based on a mbostock example (full example is at https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/899711). It superimposes several d3.js circles at various points on a google map. I'd like to add a second set of circles slightly offcentered from the original points, so that each point has a red and a blue circle.

I'm not sure about how the circles themselves are being drawn, though. There is a transform function that is applied:

```
  function transform(d) {
    d = new google.maps.LatLng(d.value[1], d.value[0]);
    d = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(d);
    return d3.select(this)
        .style("left", (d.x - padding) + "px")
        .style("top", (d.y - padding) + "px");
  }
```

and applied to each point using `each`. If I attempt to draw both circles by simply adding another set of circles to the point where the circles are appended:

```
  marker.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .attr("cx", padding)
      .attr("cy", padding)
     .append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .attr("cx", padding + 30)
      .attr("cy", padding + 30);
```

only one set of circles ends up being drawn. I'm guessing this has to do with the transform function only being applied to the last set of circles that is defined? How can I add another set of circles to the map?

Answer (score 1):

Your code appends circles to circles.    This results in invalid SVG, circles can't be children of circles.

Don't chain the .append.

```
marker.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .attr("cx", padding)
      .attr("cy", padding);

marker.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .attr("cx", padding + 30)
      .attr("cy", padding + 30);
```